# Why does NumberStyles.AllowThousands work for int.Parse but not for double.Parse in this example?

Tags: c#

To parse a string representing a number, with a comma separating thousand digits from the rest, I tried

```
int tmp1 = int.Parse("1,234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
double tmp2 = double.Parse("1,000.01", NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

The first statement is executed without issues, while the second fails with an exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
> mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Why do not both succeed?

Answer (score 16):

You should pass [`AllowDecimalPoint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [`Float`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or [`Number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) style (latter two styles are just a combination of several number styles which include `AllowDecimalPoint` flag):

```
double.Parse("1,000.01", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint)
```

When you provide some number style to parsing method, you specify *exact* style of elements which can present in the string. Styles which are not included considered as not allowed. Default combination of flags (when you don't specify style explicitly) for parsing double value is `NumberStyles.Float` and `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` flags.

Consider your first example with parsing integer - you haven't passed `AllowLeadingSign` flag. Thus the following code will throw an exception:

```
int.Parse("-1,234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands)
```

For such numbers, `AllowLeadingSign` flag should be added:

```
int.Parse("-1,234", NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign)
```

Comment: Thanks. can you explain why I have to pass the other flag?

Comment: Better yet, add to the defaults. For `int`, that's `NumberStyles.Integer`, so `int.Parse("-1,234", NumberStyles.Integer | NumberStyles.AllowThousands)` should work.

Comment: @Tim, shooting from the hip here, but it's because different cultures use `,` and `.` opposite of what you're using. In the US, "one thousand and one tenth" is represented as `1,000.1`, where as in some cultures it's represented as `1.000,1`. Specifying these additional flags helps the parser determine how to parse the value.